# How to update Bootstrap data using ajax and JSON on paging in jquery

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-ajax, bootstrap-table

I have bootstrap table that have paging. on page change fetch data from server by ajax and get json:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/GetUserList2',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: dataType,
            data: items,
            success: function (items) { 
                 console.log(items);                    
                 $(tblName).bootstrapTable({
                     data: items,
                 });
            }
        });
```

when check console, data is fetched. but table data not changed?!
and so after searching, i use this code in success:

```
        $(tblName).bootstrapTable("destroy");
        $(tblName).bootstrapTable({
            data: items,
        });
```

above code update table data but refresh table head too.
my table has custom head and i don't want refresh head section.

I used the following code but did not answer:

```
$(tblName).bootstrapTable("append",items);
```

Answer (score 1):

I change below code and worked for me:

```
 $(tblName).bootstrapTable("destroy");
    $(tblName).bootstrapTable({
        data: items,
    });
```

change to:

```
 $(tblName).bootstrapTable({
            data: items,
        });
        $(tblName).bootstrapTable('load', items);
```